# Binary Searching in Python

Tags: python, arrays, search, binary-search

So I have this problem.

> You are given a landscape in the form of a non-empty one-dimensional
>   array seq. The goal is to find an index i of a cell that is a pit. We
>   say seq[i] is a pit if seq[i] <= seq[i-1] and seq[i] <= seq[i+1]. For
>   example in the array [7, 6, 9, 7, 8], the indices 1 and 3 are pits.
>   The first or last elements are considered to be a pit if they are less
>   than or equal to their only neighbour. For example the last element of
>   [3, 2, 4, 4, 1] is a pit (and also index 1). Note that the definition
>   of a pit also includes equality; for example in [3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 6, 6,
>   8], the indices 1, 2, 3, and 6 are pits. As a special case, we also
>   define the only cell of an array of length one to be a pit as well.

I've formulated a solution using a binary search (kind of) to achieve O(log*n*) as the worst case time. But I've encountered an example which returns nothing or NONE.

```
def find_pit(seq):
    first = 0
    last = len(seq) - 1
    origlast = last
    mid = 0
    if len(seq) == 1 :
        return 0
    else:
        while first <= last & mid < last :
            mid = (first + last) // 2
            if seq[mid] <= seq[mid - 1] & seq[mid] <= seq[mid + 1]:
                return mid
            else:
                if seq[mid] > seq[mid - 1]:
                    last = mid
                else:
                    first = mid
    if seq[0] <= seq[1]:
        return 0
    elif seq[origlast] <= seq[origlast-1]:
        return (len(seq) - 1)

print(find_pit([0,1]))
print(find_pit([5, 4, 3, 6, 7]))
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What if the  `elif` statement in your code fails to satisfy the condition?

Comment: At a first glance your `&` operators should be `and` operators; you're not doing logical ands, you're doing bitwise ands.

Comment: Also it seems binary search won't solve this problem anyway since the input list is not expected to be sorted.

Comment: but what does function return on [7, 6, 9, 7, 8]?  looks to me like its only returning one element at most, otherwise it would have to append to a result list or it would have to yield, neither of which is being done.

Comment: I think you only need to move around a window of 3 elements through the list and add the index to the result list/iterator if left > current < right

Comment: @JL Peyret I had the same concern but the problem statement does say "return _an_ index of a cell that is a pit" (which it will do),  but not "return all indices of pits (which ,you are correct, it does not currently do). It is up to the OP to clarify which problem they are trying to solve.

Comment: @paisanco.  Correct, my bad, I hadn't read the exact request correctly, was running off from examples of pits given.  But point of fact, [7, 6, 9, 7, 8] returns None.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the

> & (bitwise "and")

to

> and  (logical "and")

in your code:

```
def find_pit(seq):
    first = 0
    last = len(seq) - 1
    origlast = last
    mid = 0
    if len(seq) == 1 :
        return 0
    else:
        #change next line to use logical and
        while first <= last and mid < last :  
            mid = (first + last) // 2
            #change next line to use logical and
            if seq[mid] <= seq[mid - 1] and seq[mid] <= seq[mid + 1]:
                return mid
            else:
                if seq[mid] > seq[mid - 1]:
                    last = mid
                else:
                    first = mid
    if seq[0] <= seq[1]:
        return 0
    elif seq[origlast] <= seq[origlast-1]:
        return (len(seq) - 1)


print(find_pit([0,1]))
print(find_pit([5, 4, 3, 6, 7]))
```

Running this with the above test cases will now give the result:
0 for the first list and 2 for the second.

Comment: At first I thought the `&` would be a harmless error, since `True & True` is still `True`. However, the `&` operator has a higher precedence than comparison operators, so `a < b & c < d` is interpreted as `a < (b & c) < d`, causing the problems in the questioner's code.

Answer (score 1):

seems to work at finding first pit in the given cases.  I've tweaked the call to allow multiple functions to be checked.

```
#.... original find_pit left, but not pasted in
import sys

def find_pit2(seq):

    left = sys.maxint
    maxp = len(seq)

    if maxp == 1 :
        return 0
    else:
        for pos, current in enumerate(seq):
            try:
                right = seq[pos+1]
            except IndexError:
                #rightmost, count as right neighbor as bigger
                right = sys.maxint
            #pit - smaller or equal to neighbours
            if left >= current and current <= right:
                return pos
            left = current


li_f = [find_pit, find_pit2]


for f in li_f:
    print f.__name__

    print("  ",f([0,1]))
    print("  ",f([5, 4, 3, 6, 7]))
    print("  ",f([7, 6, 9, 7, 8]))
    print("  ",f([3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 6, 6, 8]))
```

giving

```
find_pit
('  ', 0)
('  ', 2)
('  ', None)
('  ', 3)
find_pit2
('  ', 0)
('  ', 2)
('  ', 1)
('  ', 1)
```